# Auto-Completion on Busybox

Tags: autocomplete, sh, busybox

I run Busybox version 1.23.2. The default shell is Bourne shell. The auto completion works half: Suppose here are two directories `a123` and `a120`. I type `cd a` and `TAB` and I just get:

```
# cd a
a123/ a120/
# cd a
```

I cannot tab through the possibilities with `TAB`. I have to complete the full name by hand.

I tried to install bash-completion but I get only:

```
# opkg list | grep bash-completion
kmod-bash-completion - 20+git0+d9c7175859-r0 - Tools for managing Linux kernel modules
libdbus-glib-1-bash-completion - 0.104-r0 - High level language (GLib) binding for D-Bus
libglib-2.0-bash-completion - 1:2.44.0-r0 - A general-purpose utility library
util-linux-bash-completion - 2.26.1-r0 - A suite of basic system administration utilities
```

What can I do so that I can tab through the possibilities?

Comment: `bash-completion`, as its name implies, is for configuring the programmable completion provided by `bash`. It is not usable by the shell provided by Busybox (which, by the way, is the Almquist shell, `ash`, not the Bourne shell).

Comment: `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/sh` which is typically Bourne shell. Maybe it is ash on Busybox. Is there a similar functionality for my shell? As you can see there are four packages which have bash-completion in their name.